# SED command - Replace a key and value pair in JSON file - key name is similar to all Array objects

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Goal to replace - "text": "V01_08_17", with "text": "Customized String", in below json file with sed

File.json as mentioned above

```
{
  "type": "textList",
  "texts": [
    {
      "type": "textElement",
      "text": "V01_08_17",
      "aliasName": "versionScreen"
    },
    {
      "type": "textElement",
      "text": "V01_08_10_XYZ",
      "aliasName": "VersionXYZ"
    },
    {
      "type": "textElement",
      "text": "V01_08_20_ABC",
      "aliasName": "VersionABC"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Configuration",
  "observe": false,
  "revision": {
    "type": "Revision",
    "revisionNr": "0.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.74"
}
```

Tried different combinations with sed but not able to replace only the specific array object value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using text-processing tools like `awk` or `sed` for structured data like `JSON` has its limits. They can only process the textual representation of the data, not it's logical structure, and as such you'd have to write a full JSON processor in them to have a robust solution. Better use one that is already written, like [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) for example:

```bash
jq --arg from "V01_08_17" --arg to "Customized String" \
  '(.texts[].text | select(. == $from)) = $to' file.json
```

```json
{
  "type": "textList",
  "texts": [
    {
      "type": "textElement",
      "text": "V01_08_17",
      "aliasName": "versionScreen"
    },
    {
      "type": "textElement",
      "text": "V01_08_10_XYZ",
      "aliasName": "VersionXYZ"
    },
    {
      "type": "textElement",
      "text": "V01_08_20_ABC",
      "aliasName": "VersionABC"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Configuration",
  "observe": false,
  "revision": {
    "type": "Revision",
    "revisionNr": "0.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.74"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/CsGrw9rKKbY)